# Changing HTML image source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some code like below which changes the font of text under a certain condition.    `newEntryRow.find("p").find("span").css('color','red');`

Now I am trying to do the same thing but change the source of an image. I tried something like
`newEntryRow.find("img").css('src', "foo.png"`);`

How can I do this?

Comment: `src` is an HTML element node attribute, not a CSS style

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.attr` to change the attribute of an element,

```
newEntryRow.find("img").attr('src', "foo.png")
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
 newEntryRow.find("img").attr('src', "foo.png");
```

You can also use css to set the image but as a background

```
 newEntryRow.find("img").css('background-image', "url('path/to/pic')")
```

Don't forget to set width, height and no-repeat of the element.

Answer (score 0):

```
newEntryRow.find('img').attr('src', 'foo.png');
```

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 newEntryRow.find("img").attr("src","foo.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a CSS property, it's an attribute on the tag itself:

```
newEntryRow.find("img").attr('src', "foo.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery `attr()` method to set any attribute on a dom element.

```
newEntryRow.find('img').attr('src', 'foo.png');
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 0):

```
newEntryRow.find("img").attr('src', "foo.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ".css('src', "foo.png");"

use ".attr('src', "foo.png");"